# Error while inserting from Hive to Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am using CDH 4.7.1 cluster. Map seems completed 100% and failing the reduce part.
I have added the below part to hive-site.xml. Actual error message is pasted in the last part of this post. Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value> file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar, 
        file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.10.0-cdh4.7.1.jar,
        file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper.jar,
        file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
    </value>
</property>
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe
Continuing ...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat
Continuing ...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat
Continuing ...
java.lang.NullPointerException
Continuing ...
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:315)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeOp(Operator.java:377)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.LimitOperator.initializeOp(LimitOperator.java:41)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExtractOperator.initializeOp(ExtractOperator.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.configure(ExecReducer.java:150)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:469)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)


MORE ERROR LOG: FROM REDUCE TASK
2015-02-19 16:20:09,624 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.configure(ExecReducer.java:157)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeOp(Operator.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.LimitOperator.initializeOp(LimitOperator.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExtractOperator.initializeOp(ExtractOperator.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.configure(ExecReducer.java:150)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:315)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of  `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` in your `hive-env.sh`. If you could access to hive shell do the following:

```
hive> add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar; 
hive> add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.10.0-cdh4.7.1.jar;
hive> add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1 1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper.jar;
hive> add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar;
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the message. , I did this .still no luck. 2 things I can see now. One: In the detailed log - 15/02/19 05:20:56 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment: section shows all these jars along with a lot of other Jars. But this section mention only a single jar.15/02/19 05:21:01 INFO exec.ExecDriver: adding libjars: file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0-cdh4.7.1.jar.   Two: when I try "LIST JARS" in hive cli in each node, the jar listing is not consistent. Sometimes it shows only a single jar otherwise all the 5 added jars.

Comment: the  "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat " is caused cause the hive-hbase-handler-x.y.z.jar is missing

Comment: "hive --auxpath /path/to/hive-hbase-handler-0.10.0-cdh4.7.1.jar,/path/to/hbase.jar " try this

Comment: remove "hive.aux.jars.path" property just edit the "HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH" in your "hive-env.sh" :
 export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/

Comment: still same.                   export AUX_CLASSPATH=${AUX_CLASSPATH}:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:$(find /usr/share/cmf/lib/postgresql-*jdbc*.jar 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1):/usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xms268435456 -Xmx268435456 $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/

Comment: the thing surprise me is, still the cli LIST JARS command does not return all the jars we added.

Comment: this could happen actually ! list jars command could not display jars that you added but hive takes them into consideration  !

Comment: Thanks Yosr. Did you see some extra log I added to the question. Just wanted to see if see any clue on the issue.